# Image Flex is centered on other devices but not on my laptop

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web page and came across a problem, there are 4 images displayed on a flex in my page, when i click "inspect" and see how it displays on other devices, i see 2 images on top and 2 on the bottom.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCb95.png)

But when I go back and display it on my laptop i see 3 images on top and 1 at the bottom[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgFcy.jpg)

I want to know what can i do to fix it, in order that it always displays the images as in the first picture(2 on top, 2 on the bottom).

Here is a piece of my code

```
img {
width: 350px;
padding: 5px;
transition: transform .2s;
}

img:hover {
cursor: pointer;
transform: scale(1.03);
}

.container {
margin-top: 80px;
display: flex;
max-width: 1500px;
width: 100%;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This is because the flexbox is wrapping the elements. What you're probably looking for is a grid with 2 columns and 2 rows, which will keep the elements in a square formation.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will fit as many of those images with a width of 350px on one line. If it doesn't fit it will wrap them to the next line.

If you want to have always two images per line in your flex box, you could set the width of the image to 50% of the screen width. Because you have 5px of padding on each side, you could subtract that from 50% using the calc() function, like this:

```
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
```

Here's an example of how your code might look:

```css
img {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  padding: 5px;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="" />
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="" />
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="" />
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="" />
    </div>
  </body>
```